# Flutter Search bar not refreshing the initial list

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

i'm having a little trouble in getting back the initial list in my app, after searching an item.

I have a list car and i'm using code from tutorials, if i let the text in the formfield and change tabs, when i back the filter continues and the bar is empty.
I already tried 100 forms and keeps getting the same result.
Here's parts of the code.

```
List<Car> car = cars;
final _pesquisaController = TextEditingController();
```

I have a default textformfield with this controller above and a onchange calling the method below.

```
  void pesquisarCarro(String query) {
var carrosPesquisados = {
  ...car.where(
    (cars) {
      var nomedoCarro = cars.nomeCarro.toLowerCase();
      var input = query.toLowerCase();

      return nomedoCarro.contains(input);
    },
  ),
  ...car.where(
    (cars) {
      var codigodoCarro = cars.codigo.toLowerCase();
      var input = query.toLowerCase();

      return codigodoCarro.contains(input);
    },
  )
}.toList();

setState(
  () {
    cars = carrosPesquisados;
  },
);
```

}

Already tried putting the list on the initState but not work, can someone give me a light?
Like said, the search filters perfectly, the problem is when i let text in the form and change tabs in the bottomtabbar.

Answer (score 0):

is your problem is initial value always empty?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    onInit();
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((callback) {
      // set your list here
    });
  }
```

Comment: If I let some value on the textformfield and change tab, when i change back the filter continues but the formfield is empty